# Mistake in Kenny's New History of Western Philosophy

Tags: logic, aristotle

I have been reading the chapter on logic in Ancient philosophy and I think I have noticed a mistake. On page 96, Kenny introduces Aristotle's syllogism with:

Every Greek is human, Every human is mortal, Therefore, Every Greek is mortal.

On page 97, he simplifies this relationship with:

If A belongs to every B, and B belongs to every C, then, A belongs to every C.

Surely, this is wrong because it should be in the form of:

If every A belongs to B, and every B belongs to C, then, every A belongs to C.

I believe he accidentally switched up the position of every.

Am I right?

Comment: The example reverses the major and minor premises. The major premise has the predicate (‘mortal’) of the conclusion.

Comment: No, it is not wrong... "Every Greek is Human"  can be read it in two ways: the class of Greeks is included into that of Humans but also that the every "object" having the property of being Greek has also the property of being Human, because the property of being Greek implies that of being Human. This second reading (in terms of properties, i.e. universal) is the Aristotle's one: the **property** of being Human belongs to every Greek and the property of being Greek belongs to every Atenian; therefore...

Answer (score 1):

X belongs to every Y is Aristotle's vocabulary:

> B disease, C man (...) B belongs to every C (for every man is capable of disease)
> -- Aristotle, Prior Analytics

Thus, for Aristotle, the conditional "If A belongs to every B, and B belongs to every C, then, A belongs to every C." is equivalent to:

> If every B is A, and every C is B, then every C is A

Which seems good logic to me